# How to update the ng-repeat model of controller from another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

I have two `<div>` with their own controllers. The first div has a `ng-model="listEntries"`. I initialize `listEntries` in this `<div>`'s controller.

```
app.controller('firstController', function($scope,serviceForFirst){
      serviceForFirst.init();
      serviceForFirst.getList($scope);
});
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="firstController">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="each in listEntries">
     {{each.name}}
  </li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

I pass the `$scope` to the `getList()` and set the `$scope.listEntries` value in `serviceForFirst`. I then use `listEntries` as `ng-model`.

```
app.service('serviceForFirst',function(){
 var list=[];
 var init=function(){
  list = [{....}];

 };

 var getList=function($scope){
  $scope.listEntries = list;

 };
 var update=function(newEntity){
   list.push(newEntity);
 };
return{
 init:init,
 getList:getList,
 update:update
};
});
```

This is my second controller and the service associated to it. I intend to push new elements into `listAll` every time I invoke `addNew()`. This is how I'm trying to do it.

```
app.controller('secondController', function($scope,serviceForSecond){
  serviceForSecond.init();
  $scope.addNew=function(newEntity){
         serviceForSecond.addNew(newEntity);
  };
});


app.service('serviceForSecond',function(serviceForFirst){
  var entities=[];
 var init=function(){
   entities=[{....}];
 };
 var addNew=function(newEntity){
    entities.push(newEntity);
    serviceForFirst.update(newEntity);
 return{
   init:init,
   addNew:addNew
 };
});
```

The HTML for this `<div>`

```
<div ng-controller="secondController">
  ....
  <input type="text" ng-model="newName"/>
  <button ng-click="addNew(newName)"/>
  ....
</div>
```

But the list is not getting updated in the first `<div>`. If I try to do `$scope.$apply()` in `getList()` before setting `$scope.listEntries` then I get $digest already in progress error.

When I do `console.log()`, I see that the appropriate function in each the services are getting invoked but the list is not being updated.

How should I update the list?

Comment: Share the HTML to get better idea? is there any parent child relationship among controllers?

Comment: I added the HTML part of the code which uses the ng-model and the controller. There is no parent child relationship among these two controllers.

Comment: y are you passing scope, else you can get the list by returning from a service function and assign it to $scope.list in controller. And why to use 2 services, let 2nd controller add a new item to the list in the service, and let scope get the new list from the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need one service, which holds the data you intend to share among the different controllers. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/klode/9Lcoj2h6/)

template

```
<ul ng-controller='Ctrl1'>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item}}
    </li>
</ul>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newName"/>
    <button ng-click="addNew(newName)">Add</button>  
</div>
```

controllers and service

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, myListService){
    $scope.items = myListService.getList();
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, myListService){
    $scope.addNew = myListService.add;
});

app.service('myListService',function(){
    var list=[];
    init();

    function init(){
        list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    };

    var getList=function(){
        return list;
    };

    var add=function(newEntity){
        list.push(newEntity);
    };

    return{
        getList: getList,
        add: add
    };
});
```

Comment: Perfect one..but how $scope.items knows that he needs call service getList()? how binding gets update..can you explain this too inside answer

Comment: If the <div> will will be viewed with ng-view then will the myListService.init() gets invoked every time I view the div ? In this case won't the list will be reset to the initial state and the additions you made will be lost. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, if you want to initialize the list only once, you should initialize it in the service.

Comment: Great!! I was unnecessarily complicating it with different service for different controllers.

Comment: I will update the answer to initialize the list in the service.